Как присвоить if переменной?
Например:
a = if
b = elif
c = else
d = or
e = and
a True:
    print("Hello World")
b False:
    print(False)
c:
    pass

И другие подобные переменные. Возможно ли это сделать, и как? Заранее спасибо.х

Вы, наверное, сами уже увидели, что python на подобное говорит SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Никак. И не нужно этого хотеть.

Но (как я (сразу говорю, питон я практически не использую, но ...) нашел в гугле), можно скомпилировать строку текста и исполнить ее вызовом exec. См. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile (вот такая строка -- 'if True: print "hello"' в результате успешно напечатала hello) (понятно, что можно написать a="if", построить строку с текущим значением a, скомпилировать ее в переменную code и вызвать exec(code))

Вот, (не могу не похвалиться) как много можно узнать за 15 минут чтения гугла и набивки букв в терминале с интерпретаторм питона -)

Вы хотите странного, так как описанное "пожелание" сильно напоминает некий препроцессор для кода.  Для интерпретируемого языка типа питона это проблематично.

@NowhereMan, принципиальных проблем тут нет. См. мой коммент выше. (конечно, это не макросы, а динамическая трансляция генерируемого кода)

@avp так конечно можно, но будет не такой чистый код как в моём примере. Походу прийдется модуль писать ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@Zailox, а вы напишите препроцессор к питону (и будет всем питонистам счастье)
